# Is there an alternative way to identify the parameter or arguments that is used with rpm command in the rpm spec file

Tags: linux, rpm, packaging

In the rpm spec file, I need to identify the user has used `rpm -ivh` or `rpm -Uvh`. In general, `$1` value will be verified in the `%pre`. But in my case in the new rpm, we are modifying install location. In this case, when is check `$1` is showing the same value for both the `-ivh` and `-Uvh`.

```
%pre
     if [ "$1" -ge 2 ]; then
           legacy_exist=true
     if legacy_exist; then
           rm -rf *.txt
     else
           mkdir xxx
     fi
pre

%pre
     if [ "$1" -ge 2 ]; then
           legacy_exist=false
     if legacy_exist; then
           rpm -e xxx
     else
           mkdir xxx
     fi
pre
```

I want the removal of files to be done only in -Uvh usage but in my case when I have path changed rpm while setting true in both case and `$1` value is showing 2 only. If the rpm is not having the installation path change the code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should not check the command line args. `rpm -U` behaves exactly the same way as `rpm -i` when there is no package of that name installed.

The `$1` variable is the number of packages of this name which will be left on the system when the action completes. For a full set of possible values see:
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#_syntax

And please do not call rpm from scriptlet. RPM is not reentrant. Sooner or later you will break rpmdb.